# Concrete5 5.7: Database error when moving servers

Tags: database, concrete5, file-moving, concrete5-5.7

After weeks of developing I'm now trying to move my concrete5 website from my local xampp server to a paid host. I found and followed this tutorial: http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/installation/moving-a-site/

I've followed every step in detail. After finishing the guide I went ahead and test the homepage, however it is giving me two unexpected errors:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'select pkgID, pkgName, pkgIsInstalled, pkgDescription, pkgVersion, pkgHandle, pkgDateInstalled from Packages where pkgIsInstalled = ? order by pkgID asc' with params [1]: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pgqr288820_concrete5.Packages' doesn't exist

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]:
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pgqr288820_concrete5.Logs' doesn't exist' in /home/.../concrete/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php:165
Stack trace:
#0 /home/.../concrete/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php(165): PDOStatement->execute(Array)     
#1 /home/.../concrete/src/Logging/Handler/DatabaseHandler.php(31): Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /home/.../concrete/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Concrete\Core\Logging\Handler\DatabaseHandler->write(Array)
#3 /home/.../concrete/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(263): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#4 /home/.../concrete/vendor/monolog/mono ...
```

I've checked with phpMyAdmin on my production server, both tables 'packages' and 'logs' are present.
What can I do? I appreciate any comments, thanks in advance.

*Concrete5 version: 5.7.2*

Comment: Double check the casing on the tables (or disable case sensitivity for MySql)

Comment: Hi @user1712263, about your deleted question: [http://jsfiddle.net/L5u1jm5v/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/L5u1jm5v/4/) =P

Comment: Which PHP and MySQL versions are used on the production server?